# AWS CDK synth creating recursive cdk.out directories?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-cdk

I was working on a AWS CDK project for learning purposes. For context, I am learning TypeScript & node & npm and everything related at the same time because of that.

Everything was going well.
Because of a mishap, I had to restart from the Github repository instead of the local copy on my computer.

I clone the Github repository on my computer. I type `npm install` to install my dependencies. And then I type `cdk synth` which was working again perfectly well seconds before I had to clone the Git repo.

Now, the command takes forever. I investigate. I find out that the command creates recursive  cdk.out directories like this :

[image]

If someone can explain to me what is happening, I would be very happy :)

Comment: The duplicate `cdk.json` and dot-ignore files nested under `cdk.out` look suspicious.  You can safely delete your entire `cdk.out` folder.  CDK will recreate it on synth.  Delete `cdk.out`  and retry.

Comment: @fedonev did that. Same result 

Comment: Sounds like that one asset includes `cdk.out` itself.

Comment: You got me on the right path, thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Ok! After 2 hours of searching, found the culprit.

This is from the Lambda stack included in my appliation. The specific problematic line is this one :

```
code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(process.env.CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_BuildLambda || "")
```

because the environment variable is undefined on my local machine (but does exist in the CodeBuild environment that deploys my app), it goes to the default which is `""` which triggers the lambda to include the whole cdk application itself and therefore triggers the recursive build.

Now I have to find a way around this. And understand why it worked in the first place (maybe I had set the `CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_BuildLambda` variable locally.